# RxJs Observable duplicate values

Tags: rxjs, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

So i have pretty straight forward scenario. One subject and observable. When client logs in i publish success, when user logs out i publish false.

Problem is in subscribe method in LoginComponent
First time everything works great. User logs in i get one event, but after that when user logs out second time and logs in again i get 2 same events, again if user logs out and then logs in i get 3 duplicate events and so on.

AuthService.ts

```
public _loggedIn: Subject<LoggedInOrResetPassword> = new Subject();
public loggedId: Observable<LoggedInOrResetPassword> = this._loggedIn.asObservable();


obtainAccessToken(){
 // ommitted
 this.httpClient.post(environment.baseUrl + url, null, requestOptions)
                .subscribe(data => {
                  this.saveToken(data);
                  this._loggedIn.next(LoggedInOrResetPassword.createTrue());
                });
  // ommitted
}


private logout(navigateTo?: string){
    this._loggedIn.next(LoggedInOrResetPassword.createFalse());
}
```

LoginComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authservice.loggedId.subscribe( ( loggedInOrResetPassword: LoggedInOrResetPassword ) => {
    // HERE I GET DUPLICATE VALUES
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are NOT unsubscribing when `LoginComponent` is destroyed.

Your code should be changed as follows

First add an instance property to `LoginComponent` to store the subscription, such as

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  .....
  loginSubscription: Subscription;
  .....
}
```

Then change `ngOnInit` so that you store the subscription in the newly added property

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginSubscription = this.authservice.loggedId.subscribe( ( loggedInOrResetPassword: LoggedInOrResetPassword ) => {
    // HERE I GET DUPLICATE VALUES
});
```

Eventually add `ngOnDestroy` to make sure you unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed

```
ngOnDestroy {
  if (this.loginSubscription) {
    this.loginSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Take a look at the `async` pipe of Angular as an alternative method to subscribe to Observables and automatically unsubscribe.

Comment: This works thanks. Does this mean i should always unsubscribe?  And could you please explain this part "The reason is that you are unsubscribing when LoginComponent is destroyed." 

I am afraid i did not understand this because i was not unsubscribing before you showed me how to. And why this triggers duplicate events if i dont unsubscribe. Thanks

Comment: There was a typo. Correct response should have been "the reason is that you are NOT unsubscribing". I correct the answer. Generally speaking, any time you subscribe to an Observable in a Component method, you should always make sure that you have the corresponding `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`, unless you are sure that the destruction of the Component is coincident with the close of the App (e.g. like with standard AppComponent).

Comment: Instead of unsubscribing manually, you can also utilize `takeUntil` as shown in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription